# Logic of submitting multiple jobs to job scheduler using python

Tags: python

I am writing some code to submit multiple jobs to a job scheduler.

The code:

```
def submit_copasi_job_SGE(self,run_script_name,copasi_file,new_report_name):
    CT=Cluster_Tools() #initialize a custom class
    CT.change_scan_report_name(copasi_file,new_report_name) # use a custom function
    with open(run_script_name+'.sh','w') as f: #write a .sh script for submission to the job scheduler
        f.write('#!/bin/bash\n#$ -V -cwd\nmodule add apps/COPASI\nCopasiSE {}'.format(copasi_file))
    os.system('qsub {}'.format(run_script_name)) # submit to the job scheduler
    os.remove(run_script_name) # remove the run script

def submit_multi_copasi_job_SGE(self,run_script_name,copasi_file,new_report_name,n):
    CT=Cluster_Tools() #initialize custom class
    run_script_vec=[]  #create a numbered list of run script names
    for i in range(n): 
        run_script_vec.append(run_script_name+'_'+str(i))
    print run_script_vec
    for i in run_script_vec: #iterate over the run scripts with the previously defined function 
        CT.submit_copasi_job_SGE(i,copasi_file,new_report_name+str(i))
```

The first part will submit a job to the job scheduler. This is tested and it works. Now however I am trying to write a function to iterate over the first function to submit the same job multiple times (with different output file names, hence the 'change_scan_report_name' bit of the first function).

The error I get is the following:

```
  File "/home/b3053674/Models/Retinoic_Acid/Fit5/Copasi_Tools.py", line 307, in submit_copasi_job_SGE
    os.remove(run_script_name)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/b3053674/Models/Retinoic_Acid/Fit5/run_0.sh'
```

I suspect this is a logic problem, but i'm baffled and think this should work. Can anybody spot the bug?

Comment: In the line that is erroring out, are you trying to remove the file that you created in the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define the script as `with open(run_script_name+'.sh','w')`
then you try to delete `run_script_name`, however the file is called `run_script_name+".sh"`

so, the fixed version should be:

```
def submit_copasi_job_SGE(self,run_script_name,copasi_file,new_report_name):
    CT=Cluster_Tools() #initialize a custom class
    CT.change_scan_report_name(copasi_file,new_report_name) # use a custom function
    with open(run_script_name+'.sh','w') as f: #write a .sh script for submission to the job scheduler
        f.write('#!/bin/bash\n#$ -V -cwd\nmodule add apps/COPASI\nCopasiSE {}'.format(copasi_file))
    os.system('qsub {}'.format(run_script_name)) # submit to the job scheduler
    os.remove(run_script_name+'.sh') # remove the run script

def submit_multi_copasi_job_SGE(self,run_script_name,copasi_file,new_report_name,n):
    CT=Cluster_Tools() #initialize custom class
    run_script_vec=[]  #create a numbered list of run script names
    for i in range(n): 
        run_script_vec.append(run_script_name+'_'+str(i))
    print run_script_vec
    for i in run_script_vec: #iterate over the run scripts with the previously defined function 
        CT.submit_copasi_job_SGE(i,copasi_file,new_report_name+str(i))
```